# Destination host unreachable after moving to Hyper-V

Tags: networking, hyper-v

Yesterday I moved a couple of Virtual Servers to Hyper-V. All went well for the exception of one server.

After setting up the network like in all other server with a static IP, I cannot reach anywhere. The guest machine cannot ping other, nor can other reach it.

I've already tried to remove the network card on Hyper-V and added a new one, but still the same.

Any thought on what can be happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've had problems with the host's firewall & Anti-virus before, maybe disable those on both the host and guest and see what happens